# Recover Nginx Default file

Tags: nginx

I accidently deleted the my configuration file of a Nginx site at `/etc/nginx/sites-avialable`. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` containts on a symlink to the deleted file. Nevertheless (?) the website is still working. Is there any possiblity to recover the file (since Nginx still uses the config)?

Comment: Not an answer, did you restart nginx since you removed the ```/etc/nginx/sites-avialable``` because I don't believe it will serve the sites that were configured in any files located under site-available if it can't find it. But maybe there's a way look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

Comment: @sebastienvg Thank you very much! The post you referenced worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @Ben L confirmed it's working fine, let's make this the answer.

https://serverfault.com/questions/361421/dump-nginx-config-from-running-process

You need a gdb installed to dump memory regions of running process.

Then run this script after you adjusted the pid#

`# Set pid of nginx master process here
pid=8192`

`# generate gdb commands from the process's memory mappings using awk
cat /proc/$pid/maps | awk '$6 !~ "^/" {split ($1,addrs,"-"); print "dump memory mem_" addrs[1] " 0x" addrs[1] " 0x" addrs[2] ;}END{print "quit"}' > gdb-commands`

`# use gdb with the -x option to dump these memory regions to mem_* files
gdb -p $pid -x gdb-commands`

`# look for some (any) nginx.conf text
grep worker_connections mem_*
grep server_name mem_*`

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.